# traversing elements inside innnermost for loop

Tags: java

I am stuck up in a very odd situation .. that is there are two nested for loops and the inner most for loop i am testing some condition and if that condition becomes true then at that state i come out with the inner for loop while removing the element from the aray list at that index itself, through using continue statement but then now i want that same inner most for loop to continue for the next remain elements of the arraylist but rite now it is not happening... what actually happens rite now that if the condition becomes true in the inner for loop then element at that index is removed from the araylist 
and then flow goes to continue statement which again divert the flow to the beginning of inner for loop which is perfect but from there onwards , now onwards the flow from inner for loop should go inside for loop which is not happening

as per my analysis while i am removing the element from the list in the case when condition becomes true in the inner for loop that is creating the problem 
 please advise since continue again takes back the flow to the begging of inner for loop and then from there onwards the flow go the end of inner for loop  which should not happen it should go inside the for loop for remaing arraylist elements , please advise

```
//outermost for loop
for (File file : updatedFile) {

   //fetching data into the list 
   List<teetobjects> abcobjects = (List<teetobjects>) feedObjectsGetter.getObjects(file);

   //inner most for loop begains
   for (teetobjects pecdeedObject : abcobjects) {

      //checking some condition for each element in the inner most element ....
      if (st.contains(s1)) {

         // if the condition is true then removing the element of the 
         // aaraylist named abcobjects within inner for loop
         abcobjects.remove(recFeedObject);
         continue;
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. Try to break down more clearly exactly what is happening and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: There is no code after continue, what do you want it to skip? Now if there is code that is a different matter

Comment: I'd avoid adding/removing from the list that you're iterating on if I were you.  It might mess with the for loop

Comment: I think this gives a ConcurrentModificationException. You are iterating abcobjects and inside that for loop you are trying to remove object. If you want to do that you need to use CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: @SYAM Can you please post the code of copy write arraylist so that I can grasp that also

Comment: I read that 3 times and I'm thinking you're basically asking how to break out of the inner loop but continue the outer loop? As of right now, the `continue` in the code you posted is redundant/useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove objects from a container being iterated using the "for each" version of the `for` loop: if you remove an object from a collection being iterated, you get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

In order for this to work you need to use `ListIterator<T>` explicitly, and call `remove` on it:

```
List<teetobjects> abcobjects = (List<teetobjects>)feedObjectsGetter.getObjects(file);
//inner most for loop begins
ListIterator<teetobjects> iter = abcobjects.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    teetobjects pecdeedObject = iter.next();
    //checking some condition for each element in the inner most element ....
    if (st.contains(s1)) {
         // if the condition is true then removing the element of the 
         // aaraylist named abcobjects within inner for loop
         iter.remove();
         continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CopyOnWriteArrayList is a better class instead of List as when modifying list as reading writing simultaneously would give ConcurrentModicationException. There is no need to use continue as it will iterate over the remaining elements

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on comment**

There is not difference just replace List with CopyOnWriteArrayList.

```
List<teetobjects> abcobjects = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<teetobjects>();
```

in your case try

```
List<teetobjects> abcobjects = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<teetobjects>((List<teetobjects>) feedObjectsGetter.getObjects(file));
```

**Full code**

```
//outermost for loop
for (File file : updatedFile) {

   //fetching data into the list 
   List<teetobjects> abcobjects = (List<teetobjects>) feedObjectsGetter.getObjects(file);

   /**
    * ArrayList are not threadsafe. Mutative operations like remove() method inside a for-each loop will result in ConcurrentModificationException.
    * One option is to use iterator as given in solution by dasblinkenlight. But iterators are more verbose and kind of outdated (just my opinion :) )
    * An alternative is CopyOnWriteArrayList. It is a thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) 
    * are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array. All these are underlying and the user may not be aware about this. 
    * So you could use it same like ArrayList. Just like  ConcurrentHashMap for HashMap.
    * 
    * So once you have the List<teetobjects> you can convert it to CopyOnWriteArrayList and the do mutative looping
    */
   List<teetobjects> concurrentAbcobjects = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<teetobjects>(abcobjects);

   //You could also initialize this as directly passing as a constructor argument from feedObjectsGetter as
   //List<teetobjects> abcobjects = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<teetobjects>((List<teetobjects>) feedObjectsGetter.getObjects(file));

   //inner most for loop begains
   // once you have the concurrent object ready you can loop using for-each as before.
   for (teetobjects pecdeedObject : concurrentAbcobjects) {

      //checking some condition for each element in the inner most element ....
      if (st.contains(s1)) {

         // if the condition is true then removing the element of the 
         // aaraylist named abcobjects within inner for loop
         abcobjects.remove(recFeedObject);
         continue;
      }

   }
```

Comment: thanks a lot but can you please post the entire code as I have done , it would help me to grap more , please post the entire code that is convert my above code into the way you want to explain  thanks in advance

Comment: Updated answer. Please refer to the comments for more info. :)